# Xdmx unable to open display :0

Tags: arch-linux, x11, desktop

'm experimenting with `Xdmx`, for now with the systems only. I launched hem both, the client (192.168.1.221) is logged into a full Plasma session (I executed `xhost + 192.168.110`) while on the server (192.168.1.110), instead of logging in through the DM, I changed to a shell to login & execute: (only single backticks around which twm) ``` startx ``which twm`` -- /usr/bin/Xdmx :1 -display 192.168.1.110:0 -display 192.168.1.221:0 -ignorebadfontpaths ``` which gives returns:

```
(II) dmx: Generation:         1
(II) dmx: DMX version:        1.2.20070424 (DMX Project)
(II) dmx: MAXSCREENS:         16
(II) dmx: Using configuration from command line
(II) dmx: Added 192.168.1.110:0 at 0 0
(II) dmx: Added 192.168.1.221:0 right of 192.168.1.110:0
(Fatal Error) dmx: dmxOpenDisplay: Unable to open display 192.168.1.110:0

xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Why would it be unable to oprn `Unable to open display 192.168.1.110:0`? There's nothing running on `:0` yet

Comment: Did you fix this problem?

Comment: No, I actually have not...